# validity of isbns in catching jump transposition errors

Tags: computer-science

Does the isbn detect jump transpositions?

$$a_1+2a_2+3a_3+\cdots+10a_{10}=0\pmod{11}$$

I think it does because the specific formula multiplying 1 times 1st digit, 2 times 2nd digit... will give you a remainder of zero if the isbn is correct. if it's not the right isbn, then you will get a remainder $\ge 1$.

Comment: You've got the right general idea, now prove it!

Comment: Err that's where I get lost. So if, the nth digit is transposed with the (n+i)th digit, then unless n a sub (n+i) = (n+i) a sub n for some n in N, then the isbn is wrong. but this contradicts what i was trying to prove...?

Answer (score 0):

Call the sum $a_1+2a_2+3a_3+\cdots+10a_{10}=S$.  We have $S\equiv 0\pmod{11}$.  Suppose we transpose the $i^\text{th}$ and $j^\text{th}$ digits.  In order to not detect this transposition, we must have  $$S-ia_i+ia_j-ja_j+ja_i\equiv 0\pmod{11}$$
We now remove $S$ (which is 0), and rearrange to get $$(j-i)a_i\equiv (j-i)a_j\pmod{11}$$

We now need one of the important properties of modular arithmetic: 
If $ac\equiv bc\pmod{n}$ and $\gcd(c,n)=1$, then $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$

Since $11$ is prime, $i\neq j$, and $1\le i,j\le 10$, we know $\gcd(j-i,11)=1$.  Hence we may conclude that $a_i\equiv a_j\pmod{11}$.

Hence the only transpositions we can't detect are of the same two digits transposed anyway.